# Webpack polyFill - Cannot read property 'signals' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, electron, polyfills

I´m currently trying to make the lib `youtube-dl-exec` work in my electron application. The problem here is that it's not intended to run in the browser!

From what I learned since I tried to solve this issue is that Webpack 5 does no longer provide auto-polyfill, which might be part of the issue I´m facing. To overcome this situation I already tried many solutions I´ve found, but for now they only reduced the list of errors.

**My Setup**

- Electron (latest version) (electron-react-boilerplate)
- Webpack 5
- Typescript

**What I did so far?**

Installed this plugin: [node-polyfill-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-polyfill-webpack-plugin)

added in my `webpack.config.base.js`:

```
   resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.ts', '.tsx'],
    modules: [webpackPaths.srcPath, 'node_modules'],
    fallback: {
      "fs": false, //added to fix issue
      "child_process": false, //added to fix issue
    }
  },

  plugins: [
    new NodePolyfillPlugin(), //added to fix issue
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
      NODE_ENV: 'production',
    }),
  ],
};
```

This reduce the error from a lot to two errors:

[image: Error]

I already searched a lot but haven't found anything that could help me. I´m aware of a possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67785408/browserify-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-signals-of-undefined), but this Question is in my opinion poorly asked and not answered yet.